Can a photon be modeled using AC driven electron and AC driven wire loop?
Can a photon ("electromagnetic wave packet") be simulated in software as an electron bouncing up and down (for the oscillating E field) and a loop of electrons with neutralized electrostatic charges driven alternatingly (for the oscillating B field), travelling at speed c?

Would the above setup realistically simulate in software a photon moving through space?
Could we then model for instance Thompson scattering as if this "photon" were passing nearby a target electron, resulting in electromagnetic deflection of both the photon and the target electron?


Would the above setup realistically simulate in software a photon moving through space?

No. When we simulate a single photon, we'll have to take its quantum nature into account: For example, it's not certain where a photon exiting a narrow slot hits a wall, but the probability density of the points it might hit agrees with the wave model of light.
This applies to any photon; you can only make statistical statements on its impulse and location (and Heisenberg's uncertainty principle heavily constraints you on this). And you giving your photon an oscillation means you define its energy and hence impulse exactly – not possible in quantum physics.
So, yeah, no. Either you want to simulate something macroscopic such as a light wave, in which case, the thing you want to use to model your light is already what you need to simulate to correctly model your light (namely, Maxwell's equations). Or, you want to simulate a quantum individually, and then your model has not much to do with how things work.

electron bouncing up and down (for the oscillating E field)

Not at all how the e-field of light looks like: there's no "bouncing up and down", there's a "getting stronger and weaker, changing vector orientation over time"; that's fundamentally different than "bouncing", i.e. changing location of a charge. I think you might have mistaken a curve that shows the field intensity over a distance axis as showing the vertical position of something over the distance axis. That's quite a common confusion in students!

Could we then model for instance Thompson scattering as if this "photon" were passing nearby a target electron, resulting in electromagnetic deflection of both the photon and the target electron?

No, I wouldn't see how that would reflect¹ reality.

¹ no pun intended

Thank you very much. I see now that it would not work to simulate photons like this for general purposes like sending it through a double slit... What method would you recommend to numerically simulate classical photon-electron scattering, for instance the Thompson scattering? If we simulate a 3D grid of E and B field with Maxwellian time evolution rules, could the target electron be modeled within this same EM grid (since the target electron itself is emiting E and B field of its own, and what about its mass momentum properties?)

Hm, the classical model of Thomson scattering is that the incident wave (not single photon quantum, but macroscopic wave) accelerates charge carriers, which then re-emit light in a less directed way. You can of course do a charge-carrier level simulation, but that would entail having to model a lot of probability densities from wave phenomena, just to then again add a lot of emitted photons up to a statistical light intensity. So, don't do that. Classical modelling says "wave hits location of particles, we know that this absorbs x% of energy, we know that this is re-emitted istotropi-

-cally." Nothing fancy – you're aiming to model something large-scale here if you call it Thomson scattering! If you need to analyze it in a way where a purely macroscopic way doesn't suffice, you will have to accomodate the fact that Thomson is the macroscopic (low-energy) interpretation of Compton scattering. I'm no expert in the simulation – but I'm sure there's a very solid corpus of research and textbooks on that. It's an effect that physics has discovered 100 years ago, and described it mathematically since then!

Thanks again, much appreciated. One little thing about the "bouncing electron model" for the E field, though, I am still unclear say if we stand some distance to the right of this bouncing up-and-down electron, then wouldn't the x and y-component of vector E field (as seen from our observing position) cycle in both direction and strength sinusoidally, just like the prescribed E for light? How should the electron move to generate the correct shaped/direction E field for a propagating light wave?

no, not in general. Not every light wave is in TEM11 mode

I read up some on the propagating light equation, and suddenly realized I don't know how to apply it in practice beyond knowing the equation... :( Say E = [0, E_max cos (kx-wt), 0] and B = [0, 0, B_max cos (kx-wt)], which is standard presentation for a propagating em wave. Now let's have a moving electron at coordinate [1,1,1] moving with speed [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]. What is the force felt by this electron according to the above? Would the electron be attracted/repulsed by the supposed oscillating E field of this passing light? Would it feel magnetic force due to the B field of the passing light?

that representation has no freedom for phase; it is hence just one possible mode (aside from rotations, i.e., polarizations also being possible). You might enjoy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode . But seriously, you'll want to read a bit on EM theory and simulation before you build your own simulator.
